# What is a stable version of delayed_job_active_record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, github, delayed-job

I want to use delayed_job_active_record in my site, but I upgraded to the latest version and now none of my delayed jobs run properly. I don't understand why. What is a stable version of it? I am using rails 3.0.9

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.0.1 seems to be the [main release version](http://rubygems.org/gems/delayed_job) on RubyGems (at least, as of this writing).

Looking up a given gem on RubyGems is *usually* a good way to go about it. Newer, non-stable or experimental versions of gems are usually marked as pre-release.

Answer (score 0):

Were you upgrading from delayed_job 2.x?  Did you follow the instructions on GitHub?

From: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

*Upgrading from 2.x to 3.0.0 on Active Record*

Delayed Job 3.0.0 introduces a new column to the delayed_jobs table.

If you’re upgrading from Delayed Job 2.x, run the upgrade generator to create a migration to add the column.

```
$ rails generate delayed_job:upgrade
$ rake db:migrate
```